# C# how to label y axis as string rather than numbers?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, charts

i have used **c# vs2010**
winform

i made a basic chart, and added points like this:

```
chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(0, 1);
chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(1, 3);
```

but i want the y axis to display `"A"`, `"B"`, `"C"` rather than `1`,`2`,`3`,

Thank you

Comment: Are you plotting dynamically or some static values like "A" "B"...?

Comment: Also, possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232054/mschart-y-axis-and-x-axis-labelling?lq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to use only 1-26 as values, then implement this Customize event

```
private void chart1_Customize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var label in chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.CustomLabels)
        {
            label.Text = (string)char.ConvertFromUtf32(Int32.Parse(n) + 64);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. CustomLabels is exactly what I wanted. Besides the Text, starting position and the end position of the label is also required.

Answer (score 0):

There is a property called

> ChartValueType

```
chart1.Series[0].XValueType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.String
```

you can try and replace here with any of the formats.