# Looking for way to label fastline chart axis C#

Tags: c#, charts, axis-labels

I have one chart, with 8 series in it.  Each series has the same rate of data; which is 75 Hz samples from an instrument.  I'm showing the most recent 10 seconds of data, always updating.

Some of what I have:

Definition:

```
    this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 1;
    this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 751;
    //this.chart1.Series[0].Lable = "X = (#VALX - 1)/75"; // ineffective, tried various syntax
```

Management of new data insertions (showing one channel example only):

```
    ch01_series.Points.AddY(dCh01); // ch01_series is "Series", dCh01 is double
    if(ch01_series.Points.Count > 751)
    {
        ch01_series.Points.RemoveAt(0);
    }
```

The main problem has been that I cannot figure out how to label my X-Axis to show 0-10.

What I'd like to see is 11 vertical gridlines labeled "0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10"; Right now, the chart self labels, does not give me an end point, it shows "1, 201, 401, and 601".  (Writing this I'm now thinking to find a way to control the number of gridlines and will check.)

Any suggestions on (1) how to show my labels as desired, and (2) how to customize my gridlines so that I can see 11 of them instead of the 4 which MS Chart chooses to draw.  For starters I'm sure I'd be fine if I could label the X-Axis as intended regardless of the gridlines and may remove the gridlines

Some Updates:

I figured out how to set the gridline interval:

```
    this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Interval = 75;
```

And set the X-Axis interval:

```
    this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 75;
```

What remains is how I get a custom label to work, or some form of label which shows 0-10 instead of "1, 76, 151, 226, 301, 376, 451, 526, 601, 676, and 751".  The formula is (Xvalue - 1)/75, but the label syntax didn't accept my attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very similar to [MSChart Y-Axis and X-Axis Labelling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232054/mschart-y-axis-and-x-axis-labelling)

```
    chart1.Customize += chart1_Customize;

    void chart1_Customize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var label in chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels)
        {
            int xval = int.Parse(label.Text); // get the list index
            int xnewLabel = ((xval - 1) / 75); // change the range
            label.Text = xnewLabel.ToString(); // update to new value
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  I mostly had it working, but in a very brute force coded method and was going to post a "Can't this be done any easier?" follow-up question.

Comment: Glad to help, mscharts occasionally do things in ways you don't expect.